# What's the right way to connect to the thread signal from the main GUI window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, qthread

What's the right way to **connect to the** DXF_Convert **thread signal from the MainWindow** and show the message inside the update function when the thread is done?

I've done this but the message doesn't show up (the thread runs fine, though):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from gui import Ui_MainWindow

    .
    .
    .

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    .
    .
    .  

    def DXF_convert(self):
        t = DXF_Convert(self)
        t.start()
    def PDF_print(self):
        t = PDF_Print(self)
        t.start()
    def update(self, message=''):
        QMessageBox.information('Done', message)
        self.updateui()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connect(PDF_Print(), SIGNAL('Done'), self.update)
        self.connect(DXF_Convert(), SIGNAL('Done'), self.update)

class DXF_Convert(QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DXF_Convert, self).__init__(parent)


    def run(self):
        global un, fl, sq, rv
        sp = Spool(un, fl, sq, rv)
        sp.dxf_convert('local')
        self.emit(SIGNAL('Done'), 'DXF conversion done!')

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your code in line this;

```
t = DXF_Convert(self)

self.connect(DXF_Convert(), SIGNAL('Done'), self.update)
```

Reason is you must use same object to connect your signal. Like this;

```
t = DXF_Convert(self)

self.connect(t, SIGNAL('Done'), self.update)
```

---

So, I have little example for QThread PyQt4, Hope this helps

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class QTestThread (QThread):
    def run(self):
        self.emit(SIGNAL('done'), 'Thread is end')

class MainWindow (QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.TestThreadInit()

    def TestThreadInit (self):
        self.myQTestThread = QTestThread(self)
        self.connect(self.myQTestThread, SIGNAL('done'), self.update)
        self.myQTestThread.start()

    def update (self, message):
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Information', message)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myMainWindow= MainWindow()
myMainWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

---

And problem in QMessageBox is your put wrong parameter in `QMessageBox.information`
Please read this reference;

**Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmessagebox.html#information

---

Regards,